# Is this undefined behavior in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, undefined-behavior

```
int foo(int c){
    return c;
}

int main(void){
    int a=5,c;
    c = foo(--a) + a; 
}
```

Will it invoke undefined behavior in C/C++? I think no it won't.

After reading all the answers I can't figure out whether it is undefined behavior or unspecified behavior.

Comment: No, it won't because it won't compile. (Where's the semicolon!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points has a lot of information about this.

Comment: Unless you implement a compiler, or a compiler test suite, or your company employs a bunch of language lawyers, I'd question your need to even know that. Yes, there's a few people here on SO who can answer that question (and you'll find more on `comp.lang.c++.moderated` and `comp.std.c++` on Usenet), but there aren't many and even they sometimes disagree on subtle corner cases. Even more importantly, (some) compilers might disagree with them, too. If the code isn't clear-cut enough that, by one look at it, a reasonably experience programmer can say "Yep!" or "Nope!", simplify it and be done.

Comment: I answered wrong to prove a point :)

Comment: @Matt: your answer did surprise me! Had me jump in my copy of the FCD to check if I had not skipped over something! @Erik is covering us though :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it's undefined behavior - `a` and `foo(--a)` can be evaluated in any order.

For further reference, see e.g. [Sequence Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point). There's a sequence point after the complete expression, and after evaluation of the argument to `foo` - but the order of evaluation of subexpressions is unspecified, per 5/4:

> Except where noted, the order of
>   evaluation of operands of individual
>   operators and subexpressions of
>   individual expressions, and the order
>   in which side effects take place, is
>   unspecified. Between the previous
>   and next sequence point a scalar
>   object shall have its stored value
>   modified at most once by the
>   evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be
>   accessed only to determine the value
>   to be stored. The requirements of this
>   paragraph shall be met for each
>   allowable ordering of the
>   subexpressions of a full expression;
>   otherwise the behavior is undefined.

EDIT: As Prasoon points out, the behavior is *unspecified* due to **the order of evaluation ... is unspecified.**, and becomes *undefined* due to **the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be stored**

Comment: From what I can understand, it's even worse. Nothing would prevent `a` from being evaluated after `--a` but before `foo(...)`, which could matter if `foo` further alters the value of `a`.

Comment: @Eric : This is not the only reason. For example `int c = foo(k--) + foo(--j)` doesn't invoke undefiend behaviour even though the order of evaluation of `+` is unspecified.

Comment: @Eric : The behaviour is not only unspecified but it is undefined also. Read my answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

You should read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point), it will tell you that your code is undefined because `+` is not a sequence point and as such it is undefined whether `f(--a)` or `a` is evaluated first.

Comment: Or read Prasoon's excellent ___[FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)___ on the matter.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the operands of `+` operator can be evaluated in either order the behaviour is undefined because it violates the 2nd rule

1) Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.

2) **Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be stored**.

The following is well defined

```
c = foo(a-1) + a ;
```

Read [this FAQ entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) for a better understanding of undefined behaviour and sequence points.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) `+` is *not* a sequence point, so the order of evaluation is not fixed, hence you have undefined behavior.

Comment: Use the word **evaluation** in place of **execution**

Answer (score -1):

You will get warning for return type in main function else it is ok and c = 8 at the end of main().

Comment: ... no you won't and not necessarily.

Comment: yeah I agree its not necessarily. What I meant was "you may get"

Comment: -1 - this is not correct - read up on sequence points: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point